# How do the coefficients of a standard cubic function affect its graph?

Tags: graphing-functions, cubics

I know how the coefficients in quadratic functions $y=ax^2+bx+c$ affect its graph, but how exactly does the coefficients in cubic functions $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ affect the final graph?

I've read [this](https://www.quora.com/What-does-each-of-the-coefficients-in-a-cubic-function-do-and-how-it-affect-its-shape-on-a-graph) answer from Quora, but it did not really help me. My math level is Algebra 1, so is there an answer that would not exceed what I could comprehend?

Comment: Just as it's easier to interpret the constants in the representation $x \mapsto a (x - h)^2 + k$ of a quadratic function, it is in some ways easier to interpret the constants in the representation $x \mapsto a[(x - h)^3 + j(x - h)] + k$ for a cubic function. In particular, $a$ controls the asymptotic growth of the function (and its sign whether the function increases or decreases as $x$ gets large), $(h, k)$ is the point of symmetry of its graph, and $j$ is a parameter that controls the direction and strength of the "wobble" about the symmetry point: The function is injective iff $j \geq 0$.

Comment: As for quadratic functions, the number of real roots of a cubic function is controlled by the sign of its discriminant, which in this case is a rather complicated polynomial in $a, b, c, d$, but its expression in the factored representation is much simpler, $-a^2 (4 a^2 j^3 + 27 k^2)$.